# What is an opera in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, music

The genre of "opera" (as in, a particular type of theatre involving a lot of singing) post-dates the Roman Empire, and the English word for it transparently comes from the plural of *opus*. In most European languages the word has the same origin.

So if I wanted to talk about opera in Latin, what word should I use? *Opera -ae* is the obvious choice, but that seems ambiguous given how common the word *opus* is.

Comment: Latin already had *opera, -ae*, which, unlike *opus*, meant strictly willfully performed work; the distinction has been lost in the modern musical parlance. It's a more plausible immediate etymology for “opera” than the plural of *opus*, although L. *opera* ultimately ascends to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whom you are talking to. Both *opera* f. sg. and *opus* in the musical sense are obviously transparent to anyone born after 1700, and I'd go with it in a modern text.

If you are explaining opera to a Roman, though, consider how much music and singing the classical theater involved already. To them, the opera would  certainly be a kind of *drama*, so your best bet would be to emphasize the properties that distinguish it from the “default,” central definition of the concept. I can think of two major ones: music as a significant feature, and the singing. Both were already prominent in the classical theater (I am reminded of the Tacitus' account of Nero playing lyre and singing; it made me chuckle), so it perhaps should not take a massive verbiage to amplify one or both.

For the emphasis on music, Joonas' ***melicum*** sounds good to me. I cannot, however, think of a single classical word that would oppose singing to reciting, e. g. *carmen* is both a song and a poem, and *cano* is both sing and recite; it seems to me that these concepts were not separate in the Roman mind. Cic. and later Plin. used *cum symphonia canere* to describe singing.

The most concise way to convey both emphases that I can think of is the adj./p.p. *modulatum*, which, in general, implies adding rhythm to an artistic performance, thus ***drama modulatum*** for “opera”. (Note that *modulatum* has a side effect that it also might imply dancing, which was also present in the dramatic κατάβασις, but this would not probably disqualify it.) All things considered, I imagine that a concise introduction to the concept of modern opera along the lines of *drama musicā symphoniaque modulatum quid nostri operam vocat* would paint a close enough picture to a Roman of the classical times.

Answer (score 1):

[Vicipaedia](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melodrama_(musica)) — which is not the highest authority on Latin but a decent source of ideas — gives four Latin translations:
*Melodrama*, *opera*, *drama musicum*, and *drama melicum*.

If one wants to be able to make a distinction between opera, melodrama, musical drama, and other possible concepts, it is safest to pick a word close enough to the Italian original.
Choosing translations is a matter of preference.
I give more weight to clear communication than adhering to classical style.
I would find it confusing to use a completely different term in Latin, when other European languages use more or less the same word.
Therefore my suggestion is to use the first declension feminine *opera* as in Italian.
If that feels insufficiently Latinate, the next one on my list is *opus*.